# Why would singers omit 's' from "He takes/makes/etc" in song lyrics?

Tags: word-usage, tenses, lyrics

I heard it done on purpose in different songs; like here

http://www.lyricsfreak.com/m/mark+knopfler/news_20089384.html

> He's burning the grass
>   He take up a glass
>   He swallow it neat

and here

http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/johnfogerty/theoldmandowntheroad.html

> He take a thunder from the mountain
>   He take a lightning from the sky
>   He bring a strong man to his begging knee
>   He make a young girl's mama cry

These are not typos, both really do sing it like that quite clearly.

Is this meant to emphasize something? Why would they use seemingly broken English?

Comment: These artists emulate the diction of African-American predecessors in whose dialect this absence of inflection is normal.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure that Mark Knopfler did not have any African-American predecessors :); and imo his song does not imply an Africa-American protagonist. But thanks for suggestion

Comment: As far back as I can remember British rock has been profoundly influenced by the blues tradition; even as it has moved in a wide range of musical directions, the vocal styling has been pretty consistently based on the black dialect of 'classic' blues.

Comment: That's probly a big part of it; another is that they mostly don't go with music -- fricatives are mostly high-frequency noise with subtle differences, and singing to a stress-timed beat emphasizes the nuclear vowels and not the buzzy margins, one reason why half-rhymes are so common in popular music. Plus there's competition with musical instruments in the same range; it's no contest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rock and roll music has its roots in the blues, which originated in rural black American communities.  Many characteristics of the blues including scales, singing styles, and non-standard grammar, are retained to at least some extent, even in rock music that is far removed from its source in the blues.

The omission of the "s" in the verb is common to many black American dialects, and is nearly universal in the type of blues songs that are clear influences on the lyrics you cite.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think that this page "say" it best: [10 Pop Songs Ruined by Proper Grammar](http://www.rd.com/funny-stuff/top-10-songs-where-bad-grammar-sounds-good/).

"It" just a matter of style and flair.

Comment: Nice link! :) Most of the examples there are just colloquialisms, though, vs properly broken English of Knopfler's :)

Comment: @MaksimSatsikau Why can't Knopfler's broken English be colloquialisms as well?

Comment: @MaksimSatsikau Maybe because he's a Geordie? See "Voiceless stops" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geordie#Consonants. See "Early Life" of Knopfler here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Knopfler#Early_life_.281949.E2.80.931976.29.